# python regex for getting maximum number of zeros between 1 of a binary number

Tags: python, regex

I need to find out a regex for calculating the maximum number  of  zeros between 1 and a  binary number. i tried the following for getting the maximum number of zeros between 1. ie if my binary number is 110001001 it should return 3 and if my binary number is 10010000001 then it should return 6

```
import re
binaryarray=['110001001','10101001','10100001','10010000001']
p=r'(?<=1)*(0+)(?=1)*(?<=1)*(0+)(?=1)*'
for b in binaryarray:
    match1=re.search(p,b,re.I)
    if match1:
        print (b)
        if (len(match1.group(1)) > len(match1.group(2))):
             print (len(match1.group(1)))
        else:
             print (len(match1.group(2)))
    else:
        print ("no match")
```

Comment: What's the expected output for a number like 10100? 1 or 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can try this

```
import re
binaryarray=['110001001','10101001','10100001','10010000001', '00', '1']
for b in binaryarray:
    found = re.findall("(?<=1)(0+)1", b)
    if len(found) == 0:     
        print ("no match")
    else:
        print(len(max(found)))
3
2
4
6
no match           
no match
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
import re
len(max(re.findall("(?:0)+"), b)))  # if b is an element in your list
```